# Win7: Default collapse certain types when Grouping by Type

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I have no idea if this is possible..

..but I noticed that windows explorer remembers for some folders that I have collapsed some types of files (like JPEG image or system file types).

Is there any way of having some types of files always to be collapsed?

UPDATE

[image]

Notice that BAK files are collapsed

Comment: Could you kindly explain 'Collapse some files' in this context?  As ever, a screenshot would be handy.

Comment: @GuyThomas Hope this help

Comment: Sounds like a file association 'problem' Control Panel\Programs\Default Programs\Set Associations [Screen shot REALLY helped me understand]

Comment: Have you tried “Tools” –> “Folder Options…” –> “View” –> “Apply to Folders”?

Comment: @GuyThomas: No, I don't think associations are messed up at all. What he wants is that when files are grouped by type in Explorer, certain types/extension groups should be collapsed in *all* folders. I think Scott's suggestion might do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scott's comment solved the problem. It was just not Tools, but Organize/Folder and search options

[image]

Comment: After XP they started hiding menus in Explorer by default. Press Alt once to temporarily display them, and you'll see that `Tools / Folder options` still works, just as in previous versions of Windows.